# Is there a character map utility for Linux that works with terminal fonts?

Tags: linux, fonts, xorg

I'm running Ubuntu Intrepid. I'd like to see a charmap of the "fixed" font -- you know, like "xterm -font fixed". However, I can't seem to get it to work with any of the standard Linux character-map programs:

```
$ gucharmap --font=fixed
Floating point exception
```

Is there a program that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Running jaunty, gucharmap does not crash for me, but this is not the tool you realy want anyways.  it's not a font previewer, it's a a tool to help copy and paste special characters into a text area.  It only knows about unicode, not all the font's that may be installed on your system.

Have you tried xfontsel?  Not the friendliest UI, but it's been around forever - even uses the old athena widget set.
Try `xfontsel -pattern '-misc-fixed-*`

the strings just above the font are the components of the X Logical Font Description (XLFD) full name for a font.
This will let you preview the font, but other than decoding the XLFD, you don't get all the unicode info etc that you would with gucharmap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the FPE as you do when specifying the font on the command line, but when I just run gucharmap and then chose *Fixed* from the list, it looks just fine. Try that.

Comment: Fixed isn't showing up on my list, even though "xterm -font fixed" works just fine.